# "AttachedProperty" PropertyChangedCallback never calls for my LayoutAnchorable, but works on DockingManager. AvalonDock

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, attached-properties, avalondock

I am trying to use `AttachedProperty` in my AvalonDock, I want it to be part of `LayoutAnchorable` but `PropertyChangedCallback` never get called. i have binded `AttachedPropert` and i am getting the control over `ViewModel` ie: when binded property changes it trigger my `ViewModel` Property.

**My `AttachedProperty`**

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty IsCanVisibleProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("IsCanVisible", typeof(bool), typeof(AvalonDockBehaviour), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(IsCanVisiblePropertyChanged)));

    private static void IsCanVisiblePropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        LayoutAnchorable control = d as LayoutAnchorable;
        if (control != null)
        {
            control.IsVisible = (bool)e.NewValue;
        }
    }
    public static void SetIsCanVisible(DependencyObject element, bool value)
    {   
        element.SetValue(IsCanVisibleProperty, value);
    }

    public static bool GetIsCanVisible(DependencyObject element)
    {
        return (bool)element.GetValue(IsCanVisibleProperty);
    }
```

**XAML**

```
  <xcad:DockingManager>               
     <xcad:LayoutRoot >                 
        <xcad:LayoutPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >       
            <xcad:LayoutAnchorablePane >                                
                  <xcad:LayoutAnchorable Title="Folder" behv:AvalonDockBehaviour.IsCanVisible="{Binding IsHideExplorer, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                       <Views:ExplorerView DataContext="{Binding ExplorerViewModel}"/>
                  </xcad:LayoutAnchorable>
            </xcad:LayoutAnchorablePane>
        </xcad:LayoutPanel>
      </xcad:LayoutRoot>
  </xcad:DockingManager>
```

**ViewModel Property**

```
    private bool _IsHideExplorer;
    public bool IsHideExplorer 
    {
        get { return _IsHideExplorer; }
        set { _IsHideExplorer = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
    }
```

I have tried attaching the property to `DockingManager` the `PropertyChangedCallback` works. Any Help guys.

Answer (score -1):

Did you already check the DataContext of your LayoutAnchorable? Maybe the DataContext is not passed down to it. In that case the Binding would not work and your DependencyProperty is not updated.